# meaning of @P annotation in spring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple and maybe stupid question so apologies in advance..

I have been reading some spring-boot java code recently I am able to understand almost all for I have been able to find documentation everywhere.. but for example for this I still can't figure out the exact meaning (I am not able to find the annotation `@P`):

```
public MyFileEvent getEvent(
        @P("user") User user,
        @P("file") @Valid @RequestBody EventFile file) throws MyException {

    return myService.getFileEvent(file);
}
```

I understand `@Valid` and `@RequestBody` but I don't find the meaning of `@P`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/parameters/P.html):

> *"An annotation that can be used along with `AnnotationParameterNameDiscoverer` to specify parameter names. This is useful for interfaces prior to JDK 8 which cannot contain the parameter names."*

There are in fact two versions of the `@P` annotation:

- `org.springframework.security.access.method.P` since Spring 3.2 (deprecated)
- `org.springframework.security.core.parameters.P` since Spring 5.0